# The animate function for jquery seems to not work

Tags: jquery

I am practicing some basic jquery and I am trying to have this circle stretch out when it is clicked on. The css for this is fine, just the animation for it will not work.

```
<div id="circle"></div>
 <script>
    $("#circle").click(function() {
        $(this).animate({Width:"300px"}.1500);
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (you have a comma typo in you code):

```js
$("#circle").click(function() {

    $(this).animate({width:"300px"}, 1500);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As said already, you have a syntax error. But since I am assuming this is a circle, you will need to change the `width` and `height` to maintain the correct circumference.

I'd like to point out that you also need to include the jQuery UI library for `animate` to work.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qn5turj7/)**

```
$("#circle").click(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        width: "300px",
        height: "300px"
    },1500); //you need a comma, not a period
});
```